# how do i align a tpanel to a very bottom of listview item

Tags: delphi, listviewitem, delphi-xe7

what i try to do is same as this image

[image]

thing i have tried `panel1.top := ListView1.Items[i].position.Y;`

but it didnt success with this trick , is there possibly way to aligned Tpanel at a bottom  of some items

Actual code added

```
procedure Ttestthreading.streamClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, R: integer;
begin
  if stream.Caption = 'stream' then
  begin
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
      if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3] = IntToStr(UniqueID) then
      begin
        R := ListView1.Items[i].Index;
        panel2.Top := ListView1.Items[i].Position.Y;
      end;
    ExchangeItems(ListView1, R, 0);
    stream.Caption := 'stopstream';
    panel2.Visible := true;

    // start stream
  end
  else if stream.Caption = 'stopstream' then
  begin
    ExchangeItems(ListView1, R, 0);
    stream.Caption := 'stream';
    panel2.Visible := false;
    // stopstream

  end;
end;
```

Comment: So, this is FMX... Where is the gray panel in your picture ? Is it that 1 or 2 pixel high line you're pointing with the arrow ? Have you tried to set `Bottom` to the panel's `Align` property ?

Comment: this is a vcl application @TLama i created listview and draw some gradient on it , what iam trying to do is align this 1 pixel line to a buttom of my actual item height

Comment: I would say, then draw that line to the bottom of the item rectangle. But I cannot, because there's this panel thing. So you have a panel parented to a list view item (what ?) ? Or what's all this about ?

Comment: ok , i will describe , first i dont want to draw lines under all items , this 1 pixel panel is  none visible by default until some of the clients of this application click on some button to mark him self with this line under his item

Comment: Oh, so it's not a `TPanel` control, but something you just call panel. But why do you set to that `Panel1` thing `Top` property ? I'm afraid I still cannot make any sense of this. The item rendering events provide you the content rectangles, so take them and render near their `Bottom`.

Comment: actual code added for better understand

Comment: Still makes no sence. You want to draw a line under each item?

Comment: That didn't help (to me). I feel that you're doing this wrong. There are events like `OnDrawItem` where you can render the items by yourself. You're not supposed to *cover* the list view with another controls.

Comment: hmmm  , possibly i do it in very wrong way  i will try to digging more .

Comment: You want to draw a line under each item? A question with two posible answers: A)Yes b) No

Comment: @JensBorrisholt no , i want to draw line on specif item if you see the for loop up there

Comment: Have a look at the CustomDrawItem event

Comment: The CustomDrawItem event does not have a rectangle to get the postion from. OnDrawItem would be ideal but is not called with TListView in this format. I know how to do it with TListBox - that is relatively easy, but I don't see an easy way to do it with TListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.Position you will see that TListitem.Position only works when ListView view style is either vsIcon or vsSmallIcon.

So instead of using Position property you should rather use DisplayRect method http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.DisplayRect which returns the rectangle in which the List item is rendered.

Comment: If this person wants  draw inside a listbox, they should get the rectangle as you say, and then they should implement owner draw.

Comment: thank you for the links +1 and accepted because of the equation

Answer (score 0):

Take a new form, copy this code and paste it onto the form

```
object ListView1: TListView
  Left = 0
  Top = 40
  Width = 250
  Height = 296
  Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
  Columns = <>
  TabOrder = 0
end
object Panel1: TPanel
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 250
  Height = 41
  Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
  Caption = 'Panel1'
  TabOrder = 1
end
```

First I arrange the two objects at designtime. Then I set anchors on both objects.

Comment: iam afraid this is very far away from the actual question

Comment: @DelphiStudent  "align this gray panel to to very buttom of the item " raises like a million questions.  Is it one.two or 3 components. Which components it is?  If it is 3 components whats above the grey panel

Comment: look at the question to the  actual code that added there